# XSD unit test in python / sql

Tags: python, xml, unit-testing, xsd

I'm working on a data feed for an external partner. The partner defined a huge XSD schema for the XML data to be fed to them. The concep is that they'll send me a user id, and I'll send them an XML file containing data that's relevant to the user. The XML file may contains various sub-components and each component may nest deep into multiple levels.

For example, a mockup XML can be something like below:

```
<user id='abc'>
   <job>
      <title>manager</title>
      <company> 
        <name>pepsi</name 
        ....
      </company>
   </job>
   <residence>
      <address>....</address>
      ....
   </residence>
   <education>...</education> 
</user>
```

For sub-coponents, the data is sourced from different system. I need to gather the data and compose the XML components and then group them into one final XML document. While I could validate the final XML document against the XSD schema, I wonder if it's possible for me to validate each sub-component against the corresponding fraction of XSD schema?

New to XML/XSD, I might be using impropser terminologies. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Its not entirely clear what you are asking. Yes, you can validate sub-components by creating a smaller XSD. I don't know why you would want to though - validation is done by whatever xml tools you are using and isn't much development effort, so it seems like more work than its worth. You may need to think about why you are validating it before sending it - eg what happens to it if its not valid?

Comment: Thank you, @BrynLewis. It's more for TDD. The XML document is huge. It's difficult to develop code to generate the whole XML document then validate to debug.

Comment: If you want to validate a component, without having to assemble the whole XML document, then you will need a reduced XSD that only expects that component. You could create these 'sub-XSDs' for use in each test case. As an XSD is also XML, you could create  these reduced XSDs programatically (uing XSL), as they are needed. The XSL will allow you to select the subset of the XSD you need.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can validate fragments of the XML, provided that the schema contains a global element or type declaration corresponding to your fragment.

The details depend on the schema validation API you are using. If you implement the whole thing in schema-aware XSLT 3.0, then you can validate any element in the course of constructing it, which means you don't need to think of validation and document assembly as separate phases of processing, it can all be done in an integrated way; this also has the advantage that validity errors can often be detected at XSLT stylesheet compile time, which gives better diagnostics because the error message points not to the line in the constructed document that's invalid, but to the instruction in the stylesheet that's responsible for creating the invalid content.

I would always advise anyone manipulating XML in this kind of way to use a high-level language like XSLT that has been designed for the job, rather than low-level procedural APIs in a language like Python. You can of course invoke an XSLT transformation from Python. The native XSLT processor in Python only supports XSLT 1.0, but a 3.0 processor is available in the form of Saxon (my company's product). Others of course may differ: if you've spent years mastering Python, then anything else will seem difficult at first.